# Bringing matching columns with criteria together across multiplle tables

Tags: mysql

So I'm in a bit of a complex mess.

I have a schema with multiple tables. I'm trying to pull information together across the tables.

Ex.

```
Table 1

    character_infos

col

    character_id , name

Table 2

    character_skills

col

    character_id, skill_id, active_skill_level
```

I'm trying to join all of this information on a single table by character ID, Skill ID, and if active skill level is less than a number.

However, I'm losing myself in this.

I thought I could approach it like a programmer and just use and statements, but clearly not.

What I currently have, that works, only pulls from the character ID but can't define per skill_id.

```
SELECT character_id, skill_id, active_skill_level 
FROM character_skills 
WHERE character_id = 92692957 AND active_skill_level =< 4;
```

Where do I go from here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read about JOIN in any SQL tutorial.

Comment: use group by skill Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert by any means, but have been in your shoes before. From what I can see your tables only have 1 field that is common to both "character_id". On this column you can attempt an INNER JOIN.

Here's an example that may help you get going.

```
SELECT      character_infos.name,
            character_skills.active_skill_level 
FROM        character_skills 
INNER JOIN  character_skills
ON      character_infos.character_id = character_skills.character_id
WHERE       character_infos.character_id = 92692957 
AND         character_skills.active_skill_level =< 4;
```

Comment: That worked, had to mess around with it a little bit. But it got me on the right track.
Thanks!